# Importing a Swift class that implements a protocol into Objective-C class

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, import, interop

I have a class in Swift that implements a protocol:

```
class SwiftClass: SwiftProtocol {
    func test() {
        NSLog("Test");
    }
}
```

And here is the simple protocol

```
@objc protocol SwiftProtocol {
    func test()
}
```

When I import it and use it an Objective-C class, it gives this error

> Use of undeclared identifier 'SwiftClass'

1. When I make SwiftClass extend NSObject, it works fine.
2. Having and removing @objc in the protocol yields the same error.
3. The Target Membership of the 2 files point to the correct project.

Is there a way to import my class that implements a protocol? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using `@objc class SwiftClass ...` makes any difference?

Comment: `SwiftClass` must subclass `NSObject` to make it available from Objective-C. And, of course, the Objective-C source must `#import` the Swift headers (e.g., `MyApp-Swift.h` or whatever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID35, section *Swift Type Compatibility*:

> When you create a Swift class that descends from an Objective-C class,
>   the class and its members—properties, methods, subscripts, and
>   initializers—that are compatible with Objective-C are automatically
>   available from Objective-C.

This is consistent with what you observed: it works fine if `SwiftClass` extends `NSObject`.  Is there anything wrong with solving the problem this way?

Comment: Thanks! Since the class without extending NSObject works in Swift, I was confused as to why it didn't work with Obj-C but you cleared it up perfectly for me. Thank you so much!!!